# Send email to folder in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, smtpclient

I want to send email folder instead to send emails to network.

I modified the `web.config` file as

```
    <mailSettings >
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory">
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Email"/>
        </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

while my code is

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;
```

The problem is that when I use client. Send it doesn't save emails to folder and also I don't get any error.

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you doing this for testing purposes or as a permanent solution?

Comment: just for testing, for live we will sent mail over network

Comment: Can you specify what operating system an web server you are trying to do this with please.

Answer (score 1):

Take at look at [Papercut](http://papercut.codeplex.com/). I've sampled it and read great reviews.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the lines in your code where you are modifying `client. Delivery Method` - this is already set in the web.config and is redundant - so the first thing I would do is remove that.

The web config lines look ok, but I would try i) Adding a trailing slash to that folder specification, ii) Checking it exists, iii) Making sure that the required processes have permission to write to it, and iv) Checking the event logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application as Network Service (default in IIS) it's most likely it doesn't have any write permission to that folder. Try changing it to Local System and see if it helps (ONLY for testing, never use Local System context for production).